# convert Map<String,Object> to JSON and back to Map

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a `Map<String,Object>` that needs to serialise and deserialise in JSON. As it requires to be stored in db sometimes I cannot use `byte[]`. I am familiar with `Gson`. But the problem is when the Map has POJOs that are not deserialised back to their respective forms.

Consider the below map

```
Map<String,Object> data = new HashMap<>();

Car car = new Car(1);
car.setHeight(2);
car.setWeight(3);
data.put("car",car);

Bike bike = new Bike(4);
bike.setType("Sports");
bike.setColour("Red");
data.put("bike",bike);

List<Truck> trucks = new LinkedList<>();
trucks.add(new Truck(5));
trucks.add(new Truck(6));
data.put("trucks",trucks);
```

Now converting this map to JSON would result in something like this

```
{
    "car":{
        "id":1,
        "height":2,
        "weight":3
    },
    "bike":{
        "id":4,
        "type":"Sports",
        "color":"Red"
    },
    "trucks":[
        {
            "id":5
        },{
            "id":6
        }
    ]
}
```

When converting back to POJO 
it results in a `LinkedHashMap` instead of their Respective POJOs

How do I solve this problem.

Comment: It seems that it is not the real code because `put` is not a method of `List`

Comment: sorry. My mistake. Edited. It is a sample. The real code has interfaces and a little complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible because you took `Map<String, Object>` and converter don't know the type of `Object` in `Map` so its obvious that it'll return `LinkedHashMap`. What you can do is rather taking `Map` create dedicated class that represents your `JSON`.

```
public class Holder{
    private Car car;
    private Bike bike;
    private List<Truck> trucks;
    //getter-setter
}
```

Comment: No. unfortunately it is not. The reason i am using Object in the map is because It would contain any data type. can range from `Long`,`String`,... to  POJO's (extended or implemented too)

Comment: For known `POJO` use them directly like `Car`, `Bike` and for other `key-value` declare `Map<String, Object>` in Holder.

Comment: I do not have known POJO's as i said earlier it would be like

(key1 -> String)

(key2 -> Long)

(key3 -> Car)

or in some other cases it would be

(key1-> List<Car>)

Comment: God help you my friend

Comment: Haha!! Hope so !! BTW StackOverflow is my god